# In Eclipse 2019-12 How do I export memory to a flat file?

Tags: eclipse

Currently, I am using Eclipse 2019-12 to develop firmware in C for a STM32 based micro controller project. Below is image of the memory view in the current environment. I pause the debug session the capture the memory content. In the past export option with `1010` has been present next to the memory tab.

[image: Memory View]

Below is an eclipse memory view image with the export option highlighted

[image: Memory View with export option]

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**References:**

- [Exporting memory to a dump file using eclipse](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/June_2015/freertos_Exporting_memory_to_a_dump_file_using_eclipse_88d64548j.html)

Comment: As far as I see that options keeps being there for Eclipse CDT/embedded